# boost asio taking 100% cpu on read

Tags: c++, boost, winapi

i made a socket app that uses boost asio how ever it seems to take a lot of cpu when i try to read any thing from the socket.

Atm i use a wrapper class so i dont have to expose the boost header files in my header file that looks something like this:

```
class SocketHandle
{
public:
    SocketHandle()
    {
        m_pSocket = NULL;
        m_pService = NULL;
    }

    ~SocketHandle()
    {
        delete m_pSocket;
        delete m_pService;
    }

    void connect(const char* host, const char* port)
    {
        if (m_pSocket || m_pService)
            return;

        m_pService = new boost::asio::io_service();

        tcp::resolver resolver(*m_pService);
        tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), host, port);
        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
        tcp::resolver::iterator end;

        m_pSocket = new tcp::socket(*m_pService);

        boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;

        while (error && endpoint_iterator != end)
        {
            (*m_pSocket).close();
            (*m_pSocket).connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
        }

        if (error)
            throw ...
    }

    tcp::socket* operator->()
    {
        return m_pSocket;
    }

private:
     tcp::socket *m_pSocket;
     boost::asio::io_service *m_pService;
};
```

and then im reading from the socket like so:

```
size_t recv(char *data, size_t size)
{
    boost::system::error_code error;
    size_t len = (*m_pSocket)->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data, size), error);

    if (error)
               throw ...

    return len;
}
```

Am i doing something wrong? Is there a better way to read data from the socket?

Boost 1.39.0
visual c++
windows

Answer (score 1):

A change you may wish to consider (and I highly recommend) is to make your socket calls asynchronous.  That way you don't have to worry about threads being blocked or any socket calls spinning internally (which I suspect may be what you're seeing).  Instead, you simply provide a callback that will receive any errors and the number of bytes received.

There are plenty of [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) in the Boost docs that illustrate how to do this, and I've found that it lends itself to a much more efficient use of threads and processor resources.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the tight while loop:

```
// BAD.
while (error && endpoint_iterator != end)
{
    (*m_pSocket).close();
    (*m_pSocket).connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
}
```

Instead try something like:

```
try
{
    (*m_pSocket).connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
    // ...
}
catch (std::exception& ex)
{
    // Release resources, then try connecting again.
}
```

Also see these [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) at for the right idioms of using Asio.

Comment: That was from the boost asio example :P

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the free function instead,

```
size_t len = asio::read(*m_pSocket,asio::buffer(data, size), error);
```

Comment: why? is there any difference?